# Javascript square brackets used in function call

Tags: javascript, brackets

im a newbie javascripter, coming from c++/c#.
im learning a tutorial which has the following lines:

```
​function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback, callbackObj)  {
​
    callback.apply (callbackObj, [firstName, lastName]);
}
```

this was an example of using a callback function inside another function.

and i was wondering about this line :

```
 callback.apply (callbackObj, [firstName, lastName]);
```

what is the meaning of using a [ ] inside a function?

Comment: Looks like an array to me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `apply`, the assumption is that the callback method signature has 2 string parameters: `firstName` and `lastName`. The callbackObj is the context being passed to the method (in case it will call `this`)

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: @Yatir glad I could help. Please mark as accepted if that answered your question :)

Comment: Actually, this is the assumption about `callback.apply`, i.e. it is assuming `callback.apply(foo, bar)` is equal to `Function.prototype.apply.call(callback, foo, bar)`

Comment: @PaulS. is right, I didn't notice the apply at first glance. This means the callback function actually expects two variables, not in an array - firstName and lastName. The first variable is the context being passed to the method. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a literal for an array. In this case it consists of 2 elements, the first being `firstName` the second `lastName`.